# The Integral as a Uniform Limit of Step Functions

Tags: mathematics, calculus, real-analysis

Who first realized that it is possible to define the integral of a function as the limit of the integrals of a sequence of step functions that converge uniformly to the given function?

This is normally how the Lebesgue integral is taught now (although the uniform convergence is avoided by Egorov's theorem), but Lebesgue defined the integral in an analogous way to how Cauchy, Riemann and Darboux did (although he sort of flipped everyting horizontally).

Comment: I believe this is essentially due to F. Riesz, but it was likely refined by others, and I don't know enough of the details to fully answer. See [*The Uniqueness of a Riesz-type Definition of the Lebesgue Integral*](http://www.thebookshelf.auckland.ac.nz/docs/Maths/PDF/mathschron001-012.pdf) by Lee Peng-Yee (1970) *AND* [*A proof of the identity of the Riesz integral and the Lebesgue integral*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183494918) by Whyburn (1931) *AND* a google search for [Ettlinger + "horizontal functions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ettlinger++%22horizontal+functions%22).

Comment: It is not true that uniform limits of step functions give you all Lebesgue integrable functions, even not all bounded ones.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I've been away from function theory too long. Can you give an example of an integrable function which cannot be expressed as the limit of step functions (or for which there is no set of step functions which converge to said function)?   Thanks in advance

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: Dirichlet function (zero at irrationals, one at rationals) is evidently not a uniform limit of step functions. The uniform distance from any step function is $\geq 1$.

Comment: Regarding what @Alexandre Eremenko said, I wasn't sure whether the uniform convergence was to be one of the initial stages in a multi-stage process leading to the Lebesgue integrable functions. In any event, for real-valued functions (even metric space valued functions) defined on a compact interval, the property of being a uniform limit of step functions is equivalent to being a [regulated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function) (both unilateral limits exist at each interior point), and thus such functions have at most countably many discontinuities.

Comment: Maybe we should be clear that "step function" means the indicator function of an interval. It's a confusing point for learners of measure theory when we introduce approximating integrable functions by simple functions by drawing a picture of linear combinations of step functions approximating some function, even though we will need to use indicator functions of complicated Borel sets in the general case (so linear combinations of step functions make very atypical simple functions).